# Change of array dimensions causes crash c++

Tags: c++, stdarray

I need some big arrays in my program, and I was testing it with arrays of **size=16*16*12*12**.

Then I changed my program to run with **size=64*64*12*12** and *it crashed before even going to main*.

**Is the problem that such arrays take too much memory?** I tried to run the code on my laptop and then also on some more powerful desktop, in both cases it crashed immediately with the bigger array, and works for the smaller array. The array size is controlled by a const int that is declared in the beginning of the code. I use the

```
    std::array<double, (64*64*12*12)>.
```

Thanks in advance

Update:
The smallest program I wrote that has the same problem is the following:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    using namespace std;
    //declare variables
    using std::array;
    const int size_q=2;
    const int qpoints=size_q*size_q*size_q;
    const int size_k=2;
    const int kpoints=size_k*size_k*size_k;
    const int branches=12;
    const int size_ph=kpoints*branches;
    const int size_Theta=size_ph*size_ph;
    array<double, size_Theta> f_ph(array<double,size_Theta>);


    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
    array<double, size_Theta> theta1;
    f_ph(theta1);
    cout <<"Done";
    return 0;
    }
    array<double, size_Theta> f_ph(array<double,size_Theta> theta1){
    for(int i=0;i<size_Theta;i++){
    theta1[i]=1.00;
    }
    return theta1;
```

**Update: Seems like it is indeed the memory, using std::vector the program runs smoothly **

Comment: what is the data type of the array

Comment: it is a double, fixed the syntax of the question

Comment: Not with double, unlikely. Maybe you made some coding error, some out of bound access, that for some reason was no issue before? Try to reproduce it in the most smallest way (MCVE) and post your code.

Comment: Will try to do that

Comment: I agree with @Aziuth . Are you sure that is the only thing you are changing?

Comment: `std::array<double, (64*64*12*12)>` is more then 4Mb of memory. Operating systems usually don't allow to allocate more then 4Mb on the stack for a process. Use the heap. `std::vector<double, (64*64*12*12)>.`

Comment: I agree with Kamil. Alternative 2: increase the stack allocation with a linker flag. Alternative 3: make the variable static to make it part of the uninitialized section.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use a `vector` instead of an `array`?

Comment: I did this and I don't have any problem, so probably it was "just" a memory problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're most likely running out of memory on the automatic store ("stack").

You can either use a vector:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<double> arr(64*64*12*12);
arr[0]; // access first element
```

Or you can use a `unique_ptr` if you dont need the flexibility a vector offers:

```
#include <memory>
auto arr = std::make_unique<std::array<double, (64*64*12*12)>>();
(*arr)[0]; // access first element
```

Comment: Okey, I will try to do this and update the question if it works, using the correct syntax :)

Comment: BTW, was this a decent question to ask? I am still very unsure of what kind of questions are encouraged

Comment: @Jhadamard Yes it was. It even got an upvote. That's already quite something because the C++ community on here is quite strict. This was a decent question.